# How can I get my flexed content to stop wrapping?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

What I'm looking to do is have the navigation menu slide under the name for smaller screen sizes. My mark-up is this:

```html
    <header>
        <h1>My Name</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                ...
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

I have `display: flex`, `flex-direction: row` on header so it puts the h1 and nav on the same line.

[image: Pre-wrap]

When I shrink the viewport to the point that it does this, I want the entire nav to fall under the name, rather than wrap. If I put nowrap on the whitespace of both items, the nav overflows to the right.

[image: Post-wrap]

I know I can use a media-query to flip it, but I want it to respond without one. I know it's possible, but I can't quite get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is to add `header {flex-wrap: wrap;}` and `header ul {dispplay: flex;}`, so that `<h1>` and `<nav>` wrap as needed, but all `<li>`s won't wrap.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

header ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: flex;
}

header li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>My Name</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Career</li>
      <li>Blog</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```